# Laurentian Litany - How pray it?

Tags: catholicism, religious-practice, liturgy

During a prayer service in our Church, we sang the **Laurentian Litany** to Our Lady. Does someone knows if there exist any rules that say how the litany should be prayed (ex: standing up during liturgical holiday)?

This litany is also known as the **Litany of Loreto** and the **Litany of the Blessed Virgin Mary.**

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I edited the question, hoping that make sense

Comment: Makes more sense, thanks. (I don't know the answer right away, but it's an interesting question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [six approved litanies](https://www.fisheaters.com/litanies.html) within the Roman Rite of the Catholic Church. **There are no officials rules as to how to pray any of these litanies**. That said, however, there are a few traditional ways of praying them.

For example the Litany of the Saints is usually chanted while kneeling during the *Mass of Ordination* or a solemn profession of a religious. It may be chanted or recited while making a procession as on [Rogation Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogation_days).

The Litany of Loreto may be said privately or in public as a novena either recited, sung or chanted as the circumstances call.

I know of several monastic communities that will make a procession on the Feast of the Assumption and will chant the Litany of Loreto (in Latin) and end the procession at a statue of Mary (all the time remaining either walking or standing). If remaining in a church, these same communities will take the traditional posture of kneeling while reciting this litany. Once again this is only a traditional way of praying any of the litanies and the faithful are quite free to choose otherwise.

One last note: Please make sure to conclude the [Litaniae Lauretanae](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/BVM/Laurentanae.html) with the appropriate closing prayer according to the liturgical season (Christmas, Easter, Advent, etc.).

Comment: There's a [Litany to St. Michael the Arcangel](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~aversa/st_michael_litany.pdf), too.

Comment: @Geremia There are literally hundreds of litanies in use amongst the faithful.